# DownloadAsync an Url with a length of over 2100 chars

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to call a website, that is generated depending on request and has an Url length of about 2200 chars.

When I call the donwload-Method with that Url using WebClient, the whole app crashes without any error message. Here is a sample of the link: http://tinyurl.com/bpp25za

How is it possible to download the content than?

Comment: You may want to check this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url. 2200 seems to be a very long url.

Comment: I got the data using the same Url `WebClient cln = new WebClient();
byte[]  buf = cln.DownloadData("http://fahrplan.avv.de/.....");`

Comment: @L.B: I am using Silverlight/Windows Phone 7. MS does not provide this method in it... :(

Comment: I have solved it using HtmlAgilityPack. Because I parse the page, it's even better, than just to get the string, because it creates a HtmlDocument Object. Now, the solution:

    HtmlWeb hb = new HtmlWeb();
    hb.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted>(hb_LoadCompleted);
    hb.LoadAsync(url); //where url =  long url string

Now I create method for Event handler:

    void hb_LoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        string k = e.Document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        MessageBox.Show(k);
    }
That's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `WebBrowser` instead:

```
    WebBrowser browser;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = @"your_really_long_url_here";

        browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigated += new EventHandler<NavigationEventArgs>(browser_Navigated);
        browser.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    void browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string htmlContent = browser.SaveToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(htmlContent);
    }
```

Comment: even this solution is not complete. because of limitations from MS it's not possible to download the whole content.